# Prove that between any two positive real numbers there is a rational number

Tags: solution-verification, real-numbers, rational-numbers

I am having a hard time coming to grips with one assumption of [this proof](https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Efreiwald/310ratbetweenreals.pdf)

> Let $x$ and $y$ $\in\mathbb{R+}$ and without loss of generality x<y.
> We pick a natural number large enough to make $\frac{1}{n} < y-x$ ,
> for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (Archimedes axiom).
>
> Now let's call $k$ the maximum natural number such that $\frac{k}{n}<= x$, then
> $x<\frac{k+1}{n}$ (well-ordering-principle).
>
> At this point we can also know $\frac{k+1}{n}<y$ (you can prove it by contradiction).
> Thus $z = \frac{k+1}{2}$ is a rational number that satisfies $x<z<y$ where $x$ and $y$ $\in\mathbb{R}$

My question is the assumption of $k$ such that $\frac{k}{n}<=x$. Why is this a valid assumption? It seems a little too much to use $n$ as the denominator, what would be a more meticulous approach (if this is not rigorous enough)?

Comment: That proof is not correct. If $x<0$, then there is no $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac kn\leqslant x$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos reading the proof, I think it refers to positive reals only. I updated the post.

Comment: Does $0\in\Bbb N$ in this context?

Comment: I don't think so as $n$ is the denominator.

Comment: Then the proof is still wrong. If, say, $x=\frac12$ and $y=\frac74$, then $\frac11<y-x=\frac54$. But there is no $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac k1(=k)<x\left(=\frac12\right)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think the proof assumes $0\in\mathbb N$, and so $k=0$ works for your example.

Comment: @StefanAlbrecht This is the reason why I've asked the OP whether or not $0\in\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have a rigorous proof that works for arbitary real numbers :

WLOG, we have $\ x<y\ $.

Define $\ \epsilon:=y-x\ $ which is clearly positive and let $n$ be an integer with $\ n>\frac{2}{\epsilon}\ $

Then, we have $\ ny-nx=n(y-x)=n\epsilon>2\ $ , hence there is an integer $\ m\ $ with $\ nx<m<ny\ $. So we have $\ x<\frac{m}{n}<y\ $ as desired.

Comment: Why $n\epsilon>2$ follows there is an integer $m$ with $nx < m < ny$?

Comment: The difference between $nx$ and $ny$ is greater than $2$, hence there must be an integer between them.